# How can I get the values of corresponding day of the week and last week and future conditionals in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date, dayofweek, date-difference

I have a column of "Date", and I would like to obtain this conditionals that I put in a picture to easy imagination:

For example: today was 30/09/2022, take the values of the week complete from monday to sunday, (27, 28, 29), but instead of 30, put the date of the friday of the last week because 30/09/2022 is friday) so put 23, and so on, 24, and 25 to close the week.

Then, if today was 01/10/2022, put the values of the week complete from monday to sunday, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 (here I can put 30 because is a past day) and instead of 01, put 24 and 25 to close week.

NOTE: Here I put expected values in a view horizontal (It was just for have idea that i want to do. ), but could be that the code select the range of this values, when I select the original date.

[image]

Then, today is 03/10/2022, so I need the values of the next days and nex months, and I need to prolongue the date of the last week real
(26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 01 and 25) as in the example:

Here is another conditional, if the date is a non-working day, put value of the last sunday of the real week. For example:
01/11/2022 and 02/11/2022 are non-working day so:

The week would be:

```
01/11/2022   --->    26, 25, 28, 29, 30, 01 and 25
02/11/2022   --->    26, 25, 25, 29, 30, 01 and 25
```

NOTE: I have another column with non-working days

[image]

Finally, I don't want show the days when the date is 24 and 25 of december, and 31 of december and 01 of january.

[image]

Do you have any idea how can I resolve it?

I think that would be with : GETDAY() and DATEDIFF(), I've trying do it but I don't have good luck with this.

Could you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You say "if the date is a non-working day, put value of the last Sunday of the real week" but your example puts September 25 in for November 1 and 2. Also, your numbers for late December are showing September.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what you wanted, but check your example - either it or I have a mistake!

So my approach is to join each date to it's history, the 7 previous days, and then PIVOT it back to a table with 7 columns representing the past Monday, past Tuesday ...

See the code below

```
with cteNonWork as ( --Enter the dates that are "not work"
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES --Cast the first as a date and the others follow
        (CONVERT(DATE,'2022-11-01'))
        , ('2022-11-02')
    ) as SpecialDay(DateVal)
), cteNonShow as ( --Enter the dates that are "don't show"
    SELECT * --Agfain, casst the first as date and others follow
    FROM (VALUES (CONVERT(DATE,'2022-12-24'))
        , ('2022-12-25'), ('2022-12-31'), ('2023-01-01')
    ) as SpecialDay(DateVal)
), cteTally as ( --Just a tally table to make work easier
    SELECT TOP 150 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY NAME) -1 as DayNumber 
    FROM sys.objects 
), cteDate as ( --Build the list of dates
    SELECT DayNumber 
        , CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY, T.DayNumber, '2022-09-18')) as CalDate
    FROM cteTally as T
), cteDatePlus as ( --Add day of week as name and number
    SELECT *  --because the numbers are easier to do math on
        , DATENAME (DW, CalDate) as DayWkName
        , DATEPART (DW, CalDate) as DayWkNum
    FROM cteDate 
), cteDateP2 as ( --Add a column "UseDate" to dislpay last Sunday
    SELECT CalDate -- if a day is not-work. Note that we still need
    --calendar day to JOIN to the other tables
        , CASE WHEN N.DateVal IS NULL THEN CalDate
            ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 CalDate FROM cteDatePlus as LW 
                WHERE DayWkName = 'Sunday' AND LW.DayNumber  < D.DayNumber -6
                ORDER BY LW.CalDate DESC)
            END  as UseDate
        , DayWkName, DayNumber, DayWkNum
    FROM cteDatePlus as D 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cteNonWork as N on N.DateVal = D.CalDate 
), cteHist as (--Add history - for each calendar date, produce 7 rows,
    SELECT D.*, T.DayNumber + 1 as DayDiff -- with each row holding 1 of the 
        , DH.UseDate as OldDay --preceding 7 days and the name of the day
        , CONCAT('Last', DH.DayWkName) as OldName --note that the day is
    FROM cteDateP2 as D --the display day, so if non-work then it's last
        CROSS JOIN cteTally as T --Sunday. 
        INNER JOIN cteDateP2 as DH on DH.DayNumber = D.DayNumber - T.DayNumber -1
    WHERE T.DayNumber < 7
), ctePiv as ( --Now pivot this to get the 7 rows as 7 columns
    SELECT * --at this point we have the "normal" table done
    FROM (SELECT D.CalDate , D.DayWkName, OldDay,OldName  
            FROM cteHist as D) as PIn --cteDateP2 as D 
        PIVOT 
        (MAX(OldDay) FOR OldName IN (LastMonday, LastTuesday, LastWednesday
                , LastThursday, LastFriday, LastSaturday, LastSunday)) as Pvt
    WHERE CalDate >= '2022-09-26'
), cteHide as ( --but we still need to hide the rows like Dec 24&25
    SELECT P.CalDate, P.DayWkName --So we'll cast the dates to strings ...
        , CONVERT(nvarchar(50), LastMonday) as LastMonday
        , CONVERT(nvarchar(50), LastTuesday) as LastTuesday
        , CONVERT(nvarchar(50), LastWednesday) as LastWednesday
        , CONVERT(nvarchar(50), LastThursday) as LastThursday
        , CONVERT(nvarchar(50), LastFriday) as LastFriday
        , CONVERT(nvarchar(50), LastSaturday) as LastSaturday
        , CONVERT(nvarchar(50), LastSunday) as LastSunday
    FROM ctePiv as P
    WHERE P.CalDate NOT IN (SELECT N.DateVal FROM cteNonShow as N)
    UNION ALL --because UNION requires the same type for a columns, and the blanks
    SELECT P.CalDate, P.DayWkName, '' as LastMonday --are strings not dates
        , '' as LastTuesday, '' as LastWednesday
        , '' as LastThursday, '' as LastFriday
        , '' as LastSaturday, '' as LastSunday
    FROM ctePiv as P
    WHERE P.CalDate IN (SELECT N.DateVal FROM cteNonShow as N)
)SELECT * --it's done, just display!
FROM cteHide as H 
ORDER BY CalDate
```

This is the output

| CalDate | DayWkName | LastMonday | LastTuesday | LastWednesday | LastThursday | LastFriday | LastSaturday | LastSunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-26 | Monday | 2022-09-19 | 2022-09-20 | 2022-09-21 | 2022-09-22 | 2022-09-23 | 2022-09-24 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-09-27 | Tuesday | 2022-09-26 | 2022-09-20 | 2022-09-21 | 2022-09-22 | 2022-09-23 | 2022-09-24 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-09-28 | Wednesday | 2022-09-26 | 2022-09-27 | 2022-09-21 | 2022-09-22 | 2022-09-23 | 2022-09-24 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-09-29 | Thursday | 2022-09-26 | 2022-09-27 | 2022-09-28 | 2022-09-22 | 2022-09-23 | 2022-09-24 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-09-30 | Friday | 2022-09-26 | 2022-09-27 | 2022-09-28 | 2022-09-29 | 2022-09-23 | 2022-09-24 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-10-01 | Saturday | 2022-09-26 | 2022-09-27 | 2022-09-28 | 2022-09-29 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-24 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-10-02 | Sunday | 2022-09-26 | 2022-09-27 | 2022-09-28 | 2022-09-29 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-10-03 | Monday | 2022-09-26 | 2022-09-27 | 2022-09-28 | 2022-09-29 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-02 |
| 2022-10-04 | Tuesday | 2022-10-03 | 2022-09-27 | 2022-09-28 | 2022-09-29 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-02 |
| 2022-10-05 | Wednesday | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-04 | 2022-09-28 | 2022-09-29 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-02 |
| 2022-10-06 | Thursday | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-04 | 2022-10-05 | 2022-09-29 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-02 |

| CalDate | DayWkName | LastMonday | LastTuesday | LastWednesday | LastThursday | LastFriday | LastSaturday | LastSunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-23 | Sunday | 2022-10-17 | 2022-10-18 | 2022-10-19 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-21 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-10-16 |
| 2022-10-24 | Monday | 2022-10-17 | 2022-10-18 | 2022-10-19 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-21 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-25 | Tuesday | 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-18 | 2022-10-19 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-21 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-26 | Wednesday | 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-10-19 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-21 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-27 | Thursday | 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-21 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-28 | Friday | 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-27 | 2022-10-21 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-29 | Saturday | 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-27 | 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-30 | Sunday | 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-27 | 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-29 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2022-10-31 | Monday | 2022-10-24 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-27 | 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-29 | 2022-10-30 |
| 2022-11-01 | Tuesday | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-25 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-27 | 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-29 | 2022-10-30 |
| 2022-11-02 | Wednesday | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-27 | 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-29 | 2022-10-30 |
| 2022-11-03 | Thursday | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-27 | 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-29 | 2022-10-30 |
| 2022-11-04 | Friday | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-11-03 | 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-29 | 2022-10-30 |
| 2022-11-05 | Saturday | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-11-03 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-10-29 | 2022-10-30 |
| 2022-11-06 | Sunday | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-11-03 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-11-05 | 2022-10-30 |
| 2022-11-07 | Monday | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-11-03 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-06 |
| 2022-11-08 | Tuesday | 2022-11-07 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-11-03 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-06 |
| 2022-11-09 | Wednesday | 2022-11-07 | 2022-11-08 | 2022-10-23 | 2022-11-03 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-06 |
| 2022-11-10 | Thursday | 2022-11-07 | 2022-11-08 | 2022-11-09 | 2022-11-03 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-06 |
| 2022-11-11 | Friday | 2022-11-07 | 2022-11-08 | 2022-11-09 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-04 | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-06 |
| 2022-11-12 | Saturday | 2022-11-07 | 2022-11-08 | 2022-11-09 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-11 | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-06 |
| 2022-11-13 | Sunday | 2022-11-07 | 2022-11-08 | 2022-11-09 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-11 | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-06 |
| 2022-11-14 | Monday | 2022-11-07 | 2022-11-08 | 2022-11-09 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-11 | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-13 |
| 2022-11-15 | Tuesday | 2022-11-14 | 2022-11-08 | 2022-11-09 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-11 | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-13 |
| 2022-11-16 | Wednesday | 2022-11-14 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-09 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-11 | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-13 |
| 2022-11-17 | Thursday | 2022-11-14 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-16 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-11-11 | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-13 |
| 2022-11-18 | Friday | 2022-11-14 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-16 | 2022-11-17 | 2022-11-11 | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-13 |
| 2022-11-19 | Saturday | 2022-11-14 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-16 | 2022-11-17 | 2022-11-18 | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-13 |

| CalDate | DayWkName | LastMonday | LastTuesday | LastWednesday | LastThursday | LastFriday | LastSaturday | LastSunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-18 | Sunday | 2022-12-12 | 2022-12-13 | 2022-12-14 | 2022-12-15 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-12-17 | 2022-12-11 |
| 2022-12-19 | Monday | 2022-12-12 | 2022-12-13 | 2022-12-14 | 2022-12-15 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-12-17 | 2022-12-18 |
| 2022-12-20 | Tuesday | 2022-12-19 | 2022-12-13 | 2022-12-14 | 2022-12-15 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-12-17 | 2022-12-18 |
| 2022-12-21 | Wednesday | 2022-12-19 | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-14 | 2022-12-15 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-12-17 | 2022-12-18 |
| 2022-12-22 | Thursday | 2022-12-19 | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-21 | 2022-12-15 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-12-17 | 2022-12-18 |
| 2022-12-23 | Friday | 2022-12-19 | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-21 | 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-12-17 | 2022-12-18 |
| 2022-12-24 | Saturday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-12-25 | Sunday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-12-26 | Monday | 2022-12-19 | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-21 | 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-23 | 2022-12-24 | 2022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-27 | Tuesday | 2022-12-26 | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-21 | 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-23 | 2022-12-24 | 2022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-28 | Wednesday | 2022-12-26 | 2022-12-27 | 2022-12-21 | 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-23 | 2022-12-24 | 2022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-29 | Thursday | 2022-12-26 | 2022-12-27 | 2022-12-28 | 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-23 | 2022-12-24 | 2022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-30 | Friday | 2022-12-26 | 2022-12-27 | 2022-12-28 | 2022-12-29 | 2022-12-23 | 2022-12-24 | 2022-12-25 |
| 2022-12-31 | Saturday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-01 | Sunday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-02 | Monday | 2022-12-26 | 2022-12-27 | 2022-12-28 | 2022-12-29 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-31 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-03 | Tuesday | 2023-01-02 | 2022-12-27 | 2022-12-28 | 2022-12-29 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-31 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-04 | Wednesday | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2022-12-28 | 2022-12-29 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-31 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-05 | Thursday | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 | 2022-12-29 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-31 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-06 | Friday | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 | 2022-12-30 | 2022-12-31 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-07 | Saturday | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-06 | 2022-12-31 | 2023-01-01 |